# How can i copy from a Userform in Excel 2013, the value of a TextBox into a doc file using bookmarks?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, textbox

I try to figure out how to copy the values inserted into a `TextBox` in a `Userform`. I want all the values inserted into the `Userform` to be saved in a doc file which uses bookmarks.

Here is my code:

```
Sub report()
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    With wrdApp
        .documents.Open "C:\Users\ment_hoch.docx"

        .Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="ab_name"
        .Selection.TypeText text:=Me.TextBox1.text
        'Not working

        .Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="abteilung"
        .Selection.TypeText text:=ComboBox1.Value
        'Not working
    End with
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a separate Sub (below) for this - adapting your code:

```
Sub report()
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application, doc
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")


    Set doc = wrdApp.documents.Open("C:\Users\ment_hoch.docx")

    SetBookmarkText doc, "ab_name", Me.TextBox1.text 

    SetBookmarkText doc, "abteilung", ComboBox1.Value

End Sub


'Replace the text in a bookmark or insert text into an empty (zero-length) bookmark
Sub SetBookmarkText(oDoc As Word.Document, sBookmark As String, sText As String)

    Dim BMRange As Word.Range

    If oDoc.Range.Bookmarks.Exists(sBookmark) Then
      Set BMRange = oDoc.Range.Bookmarks(sBookmark).Range
      BMRange.Text = sText
      oDoc.Range.Bookmarks.Add sBookmark, BMRange
    Else
      MsgBox "Bookmark '" & sBookmark & "' not found in document '" & oDoc.Name & "'" & _
              vbCrLf & "Content not updated"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tests i figured out that it worked perfect when i used UserForm1. instead of Me

.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="ab_name"
.Selection.TypeText text:=UserForm1.TextBox1.text

.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="abteilung"
.Selection.TypeText text:=UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value

Thanks a lot for the reply :) I will try it also when i get some free time!